# Executing a script in selenium python

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to execute this script in selenium.

```
<div class="vbseo_liked">
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8355" rel="nofollow">Nyaralego</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8870" rel="nofollow">Sikonge</a>
,
<a href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/member.php?u=8979" rel="nofollow">Ab-Titchaz</a>
and
<a onclick="return vbseoui.others_click(this)" href="http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html#">11 others</a>
like this.
</div>
```

This is my code to execute it.

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElement(By.xpath(\"//div[@class='vbseo_liked']/a[contains(@onclick, 'return vbseoui.others_click(this)')]\").click()")
```

It didn't work. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the element with selenium and pass it to [`execute_script()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script) to click:

```
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', link)
```

---

Since I know the context of the problem, here is the set of things for you to do to solve it:

- click on the "11 others" link  via javascript relying on the solution provided here: [How to simulate a click with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/how-to-simulate-a-click-with-javascript)
- make a [custom expected condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377790/771848) to wait for the element text not to ends with "11 others like this." text (this is a solution to the problem you had at [Expected conditions with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29361133/expected-conditions-with-selenium/29361478#29361478)):

  ```
  class wait_for_text_not_to_end_with(object):
      def __init__(self, locator, text):
          self.locator = locator
          self.text = text

      def __call__(self, driver):
          try :
              element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text.strip()
              return not element_text.endswith(self.text)
          except StaleElementReferenceException:
              return False
  ```

Implementation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


class wait_for_text_not_to_end_with(object):
    def __init__(self, locator, text):
        self.locator = locator
        self.text = text

    def __call__(self, driver):
        try :
            element_text = EC._find_element(driver, self.locator).text.strip()
            return not element_text.endswith(self.text)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            return False


browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.maximize_window()
browser.get("http://www.jamiiforums.com/kenyan-news/225589-kenyan-and-tanzanian-surburbs.html")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("navbar_username")
password = browser.find_element_by_name("vb_login_password_hint")

username.send_keys("MarioP")
password.send_keys("codeswitching")

browser.find_element_by_class_name("loginbutton").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h2[contains(., "Redirecting")]')))
wait.until(EC.title_contains('Kenyan & Tanzanian'))
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'postlist')))

# click "11 others" link
link = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="vbseo_liked"]/a[contains(@onclick, "return vbseoui.others_click(this)")]')
link.click()
browser.execute_script("""
function eventFire(el, etype){
  if (el.fireEvent) {
    el.fireEvent('on' + etype);
  } else {
    var evObj = document.createEvent('Events');
    evObj.initEvent(etype, true, false);
    el.dispatchEvent(evObj);
  }
}

eventFire(arguments[0], "click");
""", link)

# wait for the "div" not to end with "11 others link this."
wait.until(wait_for_text_not_to_end_with((By.CLASS_NAME, 'vbseo_liked'), "11 others like this."))

print 'success!!'
browser.close()
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'arguments[0].click()')",

Comment: That was the error message it gave me.  Not sure what the reason is.

Comment: File "sele.py", line 55, in <module>
    wait.until(wait_for_text_not_to_end_with((By.CLASS_NAME, 'vbseo_liked'), "11 others like this."))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 75, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @user3078335 increase the timeout, e.g. `50` instead of `30`. The solution worked for me.

Comment: i got this error. I feel like I owe you a beer. Thank you so much for all your efforts!

Comment: @user3078335 oh, wait a minute. I think I've reproduced your latest problem, let me see.

Comment: @user3078335 funny thing. When we do two types of clicks - via selenium and via js - it works for me. Check it out, updated.

Comment: any idea how to capture the return value of a browser prompt (ideally in python)?